# Make a .NET Control transparent in VB6

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

So I've got this problem where I'm creating a control in c# .NET, and I can use it just fine in VB6. However, since you can't place borderless controls in .net containers in vb6, I've tried making a special .NET Label and exposing it to vb6.

I can get this label on my form just fine, but I can't make it transparent.

I have tried using `UserControl_AmbientChanged` but the `Ambient.BackColor` always seems to be the form's color, and not the actual parent's color (say, a frame). Same when I use `UserControl.Parent` and then the Parent's BackColor. Same with `Extender.Parent`. Even if that worked, it wouldn't be pretty in the case where the background is an image.

I've tried using `SetWindowLong` but that just makes the whole label invisible / transparent with no regards for the Caption.

I've tried using a bliting technique found here: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?438895-transparent-text-box-or-label-with-scrollbars&highlight=transparent%20TextBox But this did not work as my controls are not PictureBoxes.

I'm out of option, has anyone done this before? How? Any help at all would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you really creating an application written in Visual Basic 6 in 2013?  I have never heard of putting C# controls within a VB6 application.

Comment: Is there some incredibly good reason why you haven't simply ported the vb6 app to vb.net?

Comment: @Ramhound, I work for a large Fortune 500 company, it's not that uncommon to have large-scale production enterprise VB6 applications running in those environments. In fact we have one that serves 20K+ users and millions of transactions daily. However, slowly you begin integrating a more sustainable technology.

Comment: @Ramhound. Do a com wrapper for the .net code will work though not as well as might be hoped apparently. Like you though I would be most irritated with having to do it.

Comment: Enterprise VB6? Oh boy, glad I don't work there.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson "Enterprise VB6".... EPIC. This completely proves my statement that corporations operate based on profit alone, rather than technical efficiency.

Comment: @tijizor if I'm allowed to share my opinion here, I would either: 1 - quit immediately and get a new job that doesn't involve dinosaur useless crap, or 2 - leave the VB6 solely in VB6 with no .Net interop at all. We have a failed experience in our company where we attempted to do .Net / VB6 Interop in our flagship product, and failed miserably due to `regsvr32` + `regasm` hell. In the end the only solution that worked for us was to completely rewrite the entire application in C# + WPF.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - Legacy Systems are a different matter. I very much doubt you are creating new applications in VB6 at a Fortune 500 company. Furthermore I am aware of a COM wrapper and would never considering using it within a VB6 application.  VB .NET and C# controls are a whole different beast.

Comment: What about taking this [approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/297562zk(v=VS.71).aspx)?  The label has a background image which you can set.

Comment: @Ramhound No, I'm creating .net controls for a vb6 application in 2013.

Comment: @everyoneelse This is a task that was given to me during an internship, I can't really just quit, and so far I've been able to do a lot in VB6, it's just that one transparency problem. We will eventually move to an application entirely in C#, but competition is strong and evolving fast so we can't just stop everything for 2 years and start over in c#

Comment: @Art The article linked seems to be for vb.net... I'm having troubles with transparency in VB6.

Comment: @tijizor Yes, I know.  Try doing the equivalent C# in your label control and drop that control on your VB6 form to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Do you know why they gave that to an intern, because the response from an experienced dev would have been. "That's really not a good idea", or something along those lines anyway...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation correctly you will want to set the .NET user control background color to something distinct (say a pink color with a specific HEX color code).  Then in your VB6 application you'll set this same color code (pink) to be the transparent color within the property sheet.

I've handled transparency in VB6 user controls in this fashion for a number of years and it seems to work fine.

As for the comments regarding VB6 in 2013 for an Enterprise application, well these people obviously haven't working in the software industry for long :) VB6 has been implemented in millions of Enterprise applications that are still in use today. I would ask one question for the users that posted such comments, how can you provide the power of a VB6 ActiveX control in any other language? Answer -> You cannot.

Comment: I can't believe **millions of Enterprise applications still in use today**; possibly _millions of users served every day by thousands of Enterprise applications_.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying... My .NET control in VB6 only has the properties I have exposed through an interface in my .NET code. I can change the backcolor easily in vb6 since I exposed the backcolor property of the original .net control, but there's no "Mask Color" property or "Make this color transparent" property by default. What should I add to the .NET interface / vb6 code?